# Help replicating pseudo-BNF snippet

Tags: equations, mdwtools

I am taking notes from my textbook and am trying to replicate the snippet below (I don't care about the box around it).

[image]

I have tried using the `mdwtools` package, but it rejects the following:

```
\begin{grammar}
    $B$ = t
\alt | f
\alt | $(B \cdot B)$
\end{grammar}
```

with the error message:

```
! Use of \gr@implitem doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> $

l.59     $
          B$ ::= t
```

presumably because there are not angle brackets around the terms (a bare B without dollar signs also fails). How can I reproduce the snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One work around is to turn off the printing of the angle brackets as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
  \let\syntleft\relax
  \let\syntright\relax
    <$B$> = t
    \alt  f
    \alt  $(B \cdot B)$
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

Moving the `\let` commands to the preamble will make this affect all `grammar` environments.

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you. As they are now, do the `\let`s stay local to that one `grammar`? And moving them to the preamble will only affect other `grammar`s, not everything?

Comment: Yes, I put them inside the `grammar` environment to keep the change local.